# Visual puzzle with unfolded cubes, hatched lines

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

A friend of my provided me the following puzzle, asking for help to solve it/ We don't have any additional input information except the picture.
Answers should give a logical explanation.
[image: puzzle]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Added attribution.

Comment: This puzzle was provided to me by a friend of mine, asking for a help to solve it

Comment: Could you please ask your friend where they got it from?